# Google Ads API: getMetrics doesn't get results for all passed keywords

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm on migration from the old `Google AdWords API` to the new `Google Ads API`, using `PHP-SDK` by Google.

This is the use case, where I'm stuck:

I feed an amount of keywords (paginating them by keyword plans a 10k) to `generateHistoricalMetrics`(`$keywordPlanResource`) and collect the results.

To do so I followed instructions at https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-historical-metrics and, especially, https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-historical-metrics#mapping_to_the_ui, with using of `KeywordPlanAdGroupKeywords` (with a single ad group) and avoiding to pass a specific date range for now, relying on the default value.

Further I had to apply some filters on my keywords because of `KEYWORD_HAS_INVALID_CHARS` and `KEYWORD_TEXT_TOO_LONG`, but all the errors which I'm aware of are gone now.

Now, I found out, that the `KeywordPlanHistoricalMetrics` object does **not** contain any `keyword id` (of the form customers/*/`keywordPlanAdGroupKeywords`/*) So, I have to rely on the correct ordering. This is ok as it seems, that the original ordering of keywords is preserved within the results, as here https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional

But still I have the problem, that
`count($keywordPlanServiceClient->generateHistoricalMetrics($keywordPlanResource)->getMetrics())`  is lower then `count($passedKeywords)`, where each of `$passedKeywords` where passed to

```
new KeywordPlanAdGroupKeyword([
'text' => $passedKeyword,
'match_type' => KeywordMatchType::EXACT
'keyword_plan_ad_group' => $planAdGroupResource
]);
```

**Q**: So I have two questions here:

1. Why `getMetrics()` does not yield the same amount of results as the amount of passed keywords?
2. I'm struggling with debugging at this moment: Say, I want to know which keywords are let out. Either for providing more information at this place or just to skip them, and let my customer know, that these particular keywords were not queried. How to do this, when although I have a `keyword id` for every passed keyword I cannot match the returned metrics to them, because the `KeywordPlanHistoricalMetrics` object does not contain any `keyword id`.

**Detail**: While testing I found out, that the reducing of an amount of queried keywords reduces the amount of lost keyword data:

- 10k of queried keywords - 4,72% loss,
- 5k - 2,12%,
- 2,5k - 0,78%,
- 1,25k - 0,43%,
- 625 - 0,3%,
- 500 - 0,24%,
- 250 - 0,03%
- 200 - 0,03% of lost keywords.

But I can't imagine, that keywords should be queried one by one.

Comment: Just a guess: could it be some keywords just have no historical data given your parameters (date range, locations, language, etc) and the generateHistoricalMetrics service fails to return a row for them?

Comment: I had the same, and for me it was related to this: https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/kNm5vjwld-0 Basically, if there are close variants in your keyword plan, it will only return values for one of these keywords.